# Why is identifier "v" undefined?

Tags: c++

I'm very new to programming and I'm learning C++. I'm trying to use vectors for this exercise but they are confusing me greatly. I think this code should work but I don't know why my IDE is saying that `v` is undefined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class check_input
{
public:
    void checkInput();
    void getnum();
    void displaynum();


private:
    vector<int> x;
    int sum = 0;
    int n = -1;

};

void check_input::checkInput()
{
    sum = 0;
    n = -1;

}

void check_input::getnum()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Please enter the number of values you want to sum, starting with the first: ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 1)
    {
        cout << "the number of elements must be a positive integer" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter some integers (press '|' to stop): ";
        while (cin >> x) v.push_back(x);

        if (v.size() < n)
        {
            cout << "too few numbers; we need " << n << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) sum += v[i];
        }
    }
}


void check_input::displaynum()
{
    cout << "The sum of the first " << n << " numbers ( ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cout << v[i] << ' ';
    cout << ") is " << sum << '\n';
}
```

Comment: So where is `v` defined?

Comment: You should ask the programmer, why didn't they define `v`. We can't know why it's not defined.

Answer (score 2):

**Because you didnt defined that varible.**

Please try to define that in the **right scope**, and you will not get the IDE's error. :)

Answer (score 1):

You did not define the vector v, add `vector<int> v;` to your code